# Vue.js 2, Laravel 5.4, Passport, axios - API 'GET' Problems

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, vuejs2, axios, laravel-passport

I'm tying to get an API working with Vue.JS 2 and Laravel 5.4.
In my App.vue I have the following code:

```
export default {
  name: 'app',
  components: {
    Hello
  },
  created () {
    const postData = {
      grant_type: 'password',
      client_id: 2,
      client_secret: 'somesecret',
      username: 'my@mail.com',
      password: 'password',
      scope: ''
      }
      this.$http.post('http://localhost:8000/oauth/token', postData)
        .then(response => {
           console.log(response)
           const header = {
             'Accept': 'application/json',
             'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + response.body.access_token
           }
           this.$http.get('http://localhost:8000/api/test', {headers: header})
             .then(response => {
               console.log(response)
             })
        })
   }
}
```

While 'POST' is working without any problems, I just can't get 'GET' working.

My console.log shows the following:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'access_token' 
of undefined at eval (eval at <anonymous> (app.js:810), <anonymous>:33:51)
(anonymous) @ App.vue?86c0:29
```

Unfortunately I couldn't find any explanation why this might be happening.
Does anybody know if they changed 'access_token' to something else or why this is happening?

Hope someone knows :|

Thanks in advance!

Paul

Comment: What is your GET code? You can't send a request body via GET. You need to attach the parameters to the URL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is off the top of my head. 
But i'm sure if you are using axios as your XHR client your response body is under the 'data' parameter and not 'body'.

In summary your reference to access_token would be

`'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + response.data.access_token`

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to the following link or you can compare with the below git repository

https://github.com/safiahmed4cs/Larave-Passport-with-Vue-Vue-Router-and-axios

which has Laravel App, Laravel Passport,

Axios, Vue Js, Vue Resource and Vue Router are imported as well,

Let me know if you required more info or if you face any issues.